# Tools to expose blogging as a feature to the users of my ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks, blogs, web-frameworks

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC website with facebook integrated login. As a part of the feature of this site, I want to expose users a blogging option. Logged in users should be able to post new blogs and manage their earlier blogs. Is there a library or a project that I can include/integrate with my current site ?

Features like spam blocking, Choosable custom blog Template, would be a nice to have.

I've already looked into the following:

[Orchard:](http://www.orchardproject.net/) This seems to be more of a CMS, for an admin managing his/her blog than an option to expose blogging as a feature to the users of my site.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check umbraco?

It's free, fully templated and very flexible. Content is published in a node structure, so Are media items. You can grant permission to nodes, create Users which Will only see and be able to edit their own node/media folder